# Code bugging with "if" condition statement in android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, debugging

I use an `if` statement in order to not execute some code but that code is executed anyway, even when the condition is saying to not execute.

```
private void processImage(FirebaseVisionImage image) {
 Log.d("Works122", "esad2123vrth12ing worked2313 " + isDetected);
 if (!isDetected && permitScan) {
  Log.d("Works122", "sd12222worked2313 " + isDetected);
  detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < List < FirebaseVisionBarcode >> () {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(List < FirebaseVisionBarcode > barcodes) {
    Log.d("Works122", "trembotest " + isDetected);
    processResult(barcodes);
   }
  }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
   @Override
   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    Log.d("work12", "failure2");
   }
  });
 } else {
  Log.d("Works122", "failuresq1we2");
 }
}

private void processResult(List < FirebaseVisionBarcode > firebaseVisionBarcodes) {
 Log.d("work12", "evrth12ing worsadsadasked2313" + firebaseVisionBarcodes.size());
 if (firebaseVisionBarcodes.size() > 0) {
  isDetected = true;
  FirebaseVisionBarcode item = firebaseVisionBarcodes.get(0);
  Log.d("work12", "evrth12ing worked2313");
  int value_type = item.getValueType();
  switch (value_type) {
   case FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_TEXT:
    {
     Log.d("work12", "evrthing worked  " + item.getRawValue());
    }
    break;
   case FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_WIFI:
    {
     Log.d("Works122", "Wifi " + isDetected);
     AlertDialog diaBox = AskOption();
     diaBox.show();
    }
   default:
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

I run this code and the `if` statement is executed even when **`isDetected`** is true and after some time it is not executed anymore and starts working as it should.

This is the Log when I run:

```
    ***2019-12-26 20:02:53.425 720-720/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: trembotest     false
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.425 720-720/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: Wifi true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.441 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: esad2123vrth12ing worked2313   true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.441 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: failuresq1we2
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.507 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: esad2123vrth12ing worked2313   true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.507 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: failuresq1we2
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.570 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: esad2123vrth12ing worked2313   true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.570 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: failuresq1we2
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.605 720-720/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: trembotest     true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.605 720-720/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: Wifi true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.629 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: esad2123vrth12ing worked2313   true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.629 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: failuresq1we2
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.645 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: esad2123vrth12ing worked2313   true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.645 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: failuresq1we2
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.735 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: esad2123vrth12ing worked2313   true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.735 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: failuresq1we2
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.778 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: esad2123vrth12ing worked2313   true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.778 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: failuresq1we2
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.805 720-720/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: trembotest     true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.805 720-720/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: Wifi true
    2019-12-26 20:02:53.841 720-1025/com.vizuprice.vizuprice D/Works122: esad2123vrth12ing worked2313 

  true***
```

Even when the variable is "true" the code still runs for a while and I don't know why.

Comment: How did you determine that the `if`-condition is executed despite its condition being `false`? From what I see, within the `if`, you register some callback for some action that prints some information. This does not mean that the `if` was entered when the condition was `false` (between entering the `if` and the execution of the callback, the variable `isDetected` may well be changed to `true`). What I am missing is a printout of `"sd12222worked2313     true"`, which would support your claim.

Comment: Yes,trying to find why sd12222worked2313 is not showing but the printout  "trembotest" is being executed with "isDetected" true and the "trembotest" log is just printout if "isDetected" is false.

Comment: My English is a little bit rusty, but are you trying to say that onSuccessListener runs regardless of the "if" condition?

Comment: Actually I made the test and "sd12222worked2313" is not printout when "isDetected" is true but "trembotest" is printout,so I think onSuccess listener still is executed for a while but I don't know why if it's inside the "if" condition,if you could help me understand that I'll be Happy,thank you in advance for your support !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code didn't run directly in a block(or closure/callback named in some language), `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener` in your case.

```
public void onSuccess(List < FirebaseVisionBarcode > barcodes) {
         Log.d("Works122", "trembotest " + isDetected);
         processResult(barcodes);
}
```

This block is called only when the `detector` think it is success every time, which means '`detector` is done, it's your turn now. Handle the result from detector please'.

Once you don't need the callback result, call something named `removeOnSuccessListener`. But you should make a refer for `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener`.

---

Finally, you should `addListener` in an init step(run only once), and consider the variable inside listener.

Comment: Ok,so I can solve this problem putting the verification inside onSuccess too,right ?